# How to remove "Reminders.app" from Mac OS?

Tags: macos, mac, permission, reminders

How can I delete the folder "Reminders.app" from Mac OS when the current permissions assigned to the folder is currently *Read Only* for everyone and *Read & Write* for system?

I've tried sudo / terminal, attempted to change permissions via the finder and all attempts to dislodge the folder result in access denied.  Is rebooting into a special unprotected mode required?

Comment: What version of macOS are you using? Reminders.app is an app included with the OS and all such apps are generally locked down by Apple, more so in later versions of macOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the default apps are protected by System Integrity Protection.

> To disable System Integrity Protection, you can do the following:
>
> 1. Boot into the Recovery HD by restarting whilst holding ⌘R.
> 2. Open Terminal (from the Utilities menu).
> 3. Run the following command in Terminal:
>
>    ```
>    csrutil disable
>    ```
> 4. Restart.

<sup>Source: [Disable OS X El Capitan Rootless and permit write actions to System Integrity Protection locations](https://georgegarside.com/blog/osx/package-incompatible-installer/)</sup>

You can re-enable it once you've deleted the app.

Comment: Worked great - was finally able to move Reminders.app out of /Applications .. Thank you